# category database schema

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

**Following is my categories table:**

[image]

Can you guys please point out the pro's and con's in this design?? Actually i have `Categories` , `Sub-Categories` , `Sub-Sub-Categories` and so on.. i.e. multiple levels of Sub Categories. So is this the proper way to go??

**Categories:**

**Columns** ----------------------         **DataType**

--CategoryID     ---------------------- ---    int or varchar (am confused which one would be better)

--ParentID       ---------------------- ------    int or varchar (am confused which one would be better)

--CategoryName    ----------------------    varchar

--CategoryDesc     ----------------------   varchar

--Active           ----------------------------------   bit

--CategoryImage    ----------------------   Varchar

Comment: post the code of the table (with the indexes created, etc.), that way we can say more about it!

Comment: @aF. I have updated my question...Kindly have a look.

Comment: `CategoryId` / `ParentId` is an `int`?? Doesnt look like any int ive ever seen!

Comment: actually it is `Varchar` but i am confused which one to use?? `Int` or `Varchar` ?? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Erm, it's got letters in it, so int isn't going to work.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I know that...am asking if i change it to numbers only i.e. `int` would it be better?

Comment: @user1593175 yes `int` would be better and you can use foreign key @ parent_id with the primary key (category_id).

Comment: It would be faster and more efficient, does int give you a big enough range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, use ID's with numbers only. So, alter `CategoryID` and `ParentID` to `int`.

You can also create a primary key in `CategoryID`. And a foreign key in `Parent_ID` referencing the `CategoryID`. This way it'll be created some usefull indexes.

Comment: Thanks a lot...i was reading this article http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/   is there something similar in `SQL Server` ??

Comment: Offcourse there is. If you want you can divide into other tables!